# elasticsearch doesn't suggesting anything if the exact word is used as text?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `text suggester` of `elasticsearch`. My index contains a document which has a filed `name` and its value is `crick`

```
{
  "suggest": {
  "my-suggest" : {
  "text" : "crick",
  "term" : {
    "field" : "name",
    "sort": "score"
  }

  }
 }
}
```

it return no match, *it only returns a value if there is a misspelled*
**if I pass the exact text it return nothing** any idea !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `suggest_mode`

The suggest mode controls what suggestions are included or controls for what suggest text terms, suggestions should be suggested. Three possible values can be specified:

`missing`: Only provide suggestions for suggest text terms that are not in the index. ***This is the default.***

`popular`: Only suggest suggestions that occur in more docs then the original suggest text term.

`always`: Suggest any matching suggestions based on terms in the suggest text.

Since you haven't mentioned `suggest_mode` it is picking `missing` by default.

use this settings

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "my-suggest" : {
      "text" : "crick",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "name",
        "sort": "score",
        "suggest_mode": "always"
       }
    }
  }
}
```